# Evaluation of Real-Valued Integrals (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

How to get calculate the integration of follwing:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{a + cos t} (a>1)$$

My attempt:

let, $z=e^{it}$
$\implies dt = \frac{dz}{it}$

and

$$\cos t = \frac{z + \frac{1}{z}}{2}$$

On substituting everything in the integral I got:

$$\frac{2}{i}\int_{c} \frac{dz}{z^2+2az+1}$$

Now how do I decompose this fraction so that I can use the Residue Theorem? Or is there anyother way to solve this??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of contrast, since the factorisation has been shown by others, we can proceed like this: the roots of the denominator $z^2+2az + 1$ are distinct
$$
z_{\pm} = -a \pm \sqrt{a^2-1}
$$ 
and only one lies within $C$, *i.e.* $z_+$; one can use the formula for the residue in a simple pole: since $(z^2+2az+1)' = 2z+2a$,
$$
\text{Res}\frac{2}{i(z^2+2az+1)}\Big|_{z=z_+} = \frac{2}{i(2z+2a)}\Big|_{z=z_+}=
\frac{1}{i(a-a+\sqrt{a^2-1})}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}.
$$
Hence finally
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{a+\cos t} = i2\pi \frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$z^2+2az+1=\left(z+a-\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)\left(z+a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)$$

Comment: but in the question, $a>1$ so there will be only one case?

Comment: yes, I didn't see this point.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The denominator: $z^2+2az+1$ can be easily factorize using quadratic formula as follows $$z^2+2az+1=(z+a-\sqrt{a^2-1})(z+a+\sqrt{a^2-1})$$
hence, $$\frac{1}{z^2+2az+1}=\frac{A}{z+a-\sqrt{a^2-1}}+\frac{B}{z+a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a^2-1}}\left(\frac{1}{z+a-\sqrt{a^2-1}}-\frac{1}{z+a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)$$